# React Native Expo , the intialized custom socket connection shows error:

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, websocket, expo

I want a help and it would be very grateful if anyone would help me to debug the code and tell me whats am I doing wrong here: my custom websocket hook
the error I get is that, it prints out the socket not open even after initializing it and trying to call it by child components: , when the it is opened, it shows the successful connection status and redirects but when I execute the actions of the instantiated hook, it gives error, It would be very grateful if any could help me debug error and help improve my code
the custom hook file

```js
import { useGreenhouseStore } from "../../zustand/store"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useWebSocket = ({ id }: {
  id: string
}) => {
  const store = useGreenhouseStore();
  const greenhouse = store.greenhouses.find((g) => g.id === id);
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState<WebSocket | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.onmessage = (msg) => {
        const [type, data] = msg.data.split(":");
        switch (type) {
          case "temperature":
            store.updateGreenhouse(id, { temperature: Number(data) });
            break;
          case "humidity":
            store.updateGreenhouse(id, { humidity: Number(data) });
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }, [socket, setSocket]);

  const connect = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://${greenhouse?.ipAddress}:81`);
      ws.onopen = () => {
        console.log("WebSocket connected");
        setSocket(ws);
        res(ws)
      };
      ws.onerror = (e) => {
        rej(e)
      };
    })
  }
  const sendMessage = (message: string) => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.send(message);
    } else {
      console.error("Socket not open");
    }
  }
  
  const disconnect = () => {
    socket?.close();
  }
  return {
    connect,
    sendMessage,
    disconnect,
  }
}

export default useWebSocket;
```

The file where the hook is used:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Pressable, View, ActivityIndicator, Text } from "react-native";
import CustomModal from "../ui/Modal";
import Icons from "../../assets/Icons/Icons";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";
import { useGreenhouseStore } from "../../zustand/store";
import useWebSocket from "../../config/hooks/wsservice";

type ConnectionMsgTypes =
  | "Connected"
  | "Not Connected"
  | "Connection Failed"
  | "Connecting";

export default function WSTestConnectionForm({
  id,
  ipAddress,
  showForm,
  setShowForm,
}: {
  id: string;
  ipAddress: string;
  showForm: boolean;
  setShowForm: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}) {
  const [connecting, setConnecting] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [conMsg, setConMsg] = useState<ConnectionMsgTypes>("Not Connected");
  const store = useGreenhouseStore();
  const greenhouse = store.greenhouses.find((res) => res.id === id);
  const router = useRouter();

  const websocket = useWebSocket({ id: greenhouse?.id as string });

  const testConnection = async () => {
    setConnecting(true);
    try {
      store.updateGreenhouse(id, {
        ws: websocket,
      });
      await greenhouse?.ws.connect();
      setConnected(true);
      setConMsg("Connected");
      store.updateGreenhouse(id, { isConnected: true });
      router.push(`/tabs/Home/Greenhouse/${id}`);
    } catch (error) {
      setConnected(false);
      setConMsg("Connection Failed");
      store.updateGreenhouse(id, { isConnected: false });
    } finally {
      setConnecting(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <CustomModal
      modalTitle="Local Connection Test"
      modalVisible={showForm}
      setModalVisible={setShowForm}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "column",
          gap: 10,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          position: "relative",
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            fontWeight: "bold",
          }}
        >
          Testing connection with {ipAddress}
        </Text>
        {/* Circular border */}

        {/* Button */}
        <Pressable
          disabled={connecting}
          onPress={testConnection}
          style={({ pressed }) => [
            {
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "center",
              backgroundColor: "#E0E0E0",
              padding: 15,
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              borderRadius: 999,
              alignItems: "center",
              elevation: pressed ? 10 : 5, // Change the elevation on press for an interactive effect
              borderWidth: connected ? 2 : 0,
              borderColor: connected ? "green" : "red",
            },
            Platform.OS === "ios"
              ? {
                shadowColor: "#000",
                shadowOffset: {
                  width: 4,
                  height: 9,
                },
                shadowOpacity: 1,
                shadowRadius: 3,
              }
              : {}, // Android might not need these shadow properties if elevation is set
          ]}
        >
          {connected ? (
            <Icons.passedConnection size={32} />
          ) : connecting ? (
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="yellowgreen" />
          ) : (
            <Icons.failedConnection size={32} />
          )}
        </Pressable>
        <Text
          style={{
            color:
              conMsg === "Connected"
                ? "green"
                : conMsg === "Not Connected" || conMsg === "Connection Failed"
                  ? "red"
                  : conMsg === "Connecting"
                    ? "orange"
                    : "black", // Default color
          }}
        >
          {conMsg}
        </Text>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            gap: 5,
          }}
        >
          <Icons.help size={16} color="#A0A0A0" />
          <Text
            style={{
              color: "#A0A0A0",
            }}
          >
            Press the button for connection
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </CustomModal>
  );
}
```

The action where the sendMessage function is executed:

```js
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { View, Text } from "native-base";
import { useNavigation } from "expo-router";
import { useLocalSearchParams } from "expo-router";
import { Pressable } from "react-native";
import Icons from "../../../../../assets/Icons/Icons";
import TemperatureControllerContainer from "../../../../../components/TemperatureController";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useGreenhouseStore } from "../../../../../zustand/store";

export default function ParamsContainer() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { id } = useLocalSearchParams<{ id: string }>();
  const store = useGreenhouseStore();
  const greenhouse = store.greenhouses.find((res) => res.id === id);
  const [state, opState] = useState<boolean>(greenhouse?.ventilationFanState || false);
  const toggleState = () => {
    const updatedState = !state; // Calculate the updated state value
    // Perform actions based on the updatedState
    if (!updatedState) {
      greenhouse?.ws.sendMessage("light:off");
      store.updateGreenhouse(id as string, {
        ...greenhouse,
        ventilationFanState: false
      });
    } else {
      greenhouse?.ws.sendMessage("light:on");
      store.updateGreenhouse(id as string, {
        ...greenhouse,
        ventilationFanState: true
      });
    }
    opState(updatedState); // Update the state after performing actions
  };
  return (
    <View style={{
      padding: 20
    }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          header: () => {
            return (
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  alignContent: "center",
                  padding: 10,
                  gap: 10,
                  backgroundColor: "green"
                }}
              >
                <Pressable
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.goBack();
                  }}
                >
                  <Icons.navigateBack color="black" size={32} />
                </Pressable>
                <View
                  flexDirection="column"
                  justifyContent="center"
                >
                  <Text
                    color="#fff"
                    w="container"
                    fontSize="xl"
                  >Manage Temperature</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <TemperatureControllerContainer
        state={state}
        setState={toggleState} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

By the way I m storing that initailized hook in zustand store:

```js
interface totalGreenhouseState {
    count: number;
    greenhouses: GreenhouseState[];
}
interface ws {
    sendMessage: (message: string) => void;
    connect: () => Promise<void>;
    disconnect: () => void;
}

interface GreenhouseState {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    backgroundImage: string;
    ipAddress: string;
    isConnected: boolean;
    //parameter
    temperature: number;
    humidity: number;
    soil_moisture: number;
    //end parameters 
    ventilationFanState: boolean;
    lightState: boolean;
    ws: any;
}

export { GreenhouseState, totalGreenhouseState };
```

I tried the above code and try to debug with GPT, but of no luck